# NullPointerException at the first line at getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, null

I am getting a nullpointer exception at getReadbleDatabase

```
 public List<Offer> getOffers(String offer_category)
        {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String sql = "select * from offer_db "+TABLE_OFFER + " where "+ OFFER_CATEGORY+ " is "+ offer_category;
            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
            cur.moveToFirst();
       }
```

here is the logcat data

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.example.shreyfrapp.DatabaseHandler.getOffers(DatabaseHandler.java:61)
>   at com.example.shreyfrapp.FragmentTab1.onCreate(FragmentTab1.java:39)
>   at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678) at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
>   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Assuming the logcat shows the NPE in `getDatabaseLocked()`, make sure you're passing a valid `Context` to your sqlite helper.

Comment: While you grab your logcat, take a look at [some SQLite Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) - you need a `.` between your database + table name, and also need to be using `=` instead of `is` to compare against a column value, and quotations around your string

Comment: i have posted the logcat...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883777/android-nullpointerexception-getdatabaselocked/21883908

Answer (score 0):

Give the query in capital and try "=" in the place of "is".why are u moving the cursor to first in select query?

Comment: the error is coming up where i am instantiating the database object. The query has to be executed later.

Comment: actually which db are u accessing?